# PHP Error Warning: Parameter 1 expected to be a reference

Tags: php, joomla

I am "familiar" with PHP and my friend had his site broken with error:

```
Warning: Parameter 1 to Some_function_name() expected to be a reference, 
value given in /.../public_html/includes/tng/tNG.class.php on line 219
```

line 219:

```
$ret = call_user_func_array($callBackFunction,$tempParam);
```

I am not sure what happened on his server, but hosting company team said something about the Joomla and PHP conflict. How can I fix it?

Comment: What is the value of `$callBackFunction`? It should be the name of another defined function, as a string.

Comment: Check what php version your joomla version requires.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning: mysql_fetch_* expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11674312/warning-mysql-fetch-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-error)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check the function signature of `Some_Function_name()`, you probably have something like:

```
function Some_Function_name(&$param1)
{
    // ...
```

This is a PHP 5.3 compatibility issue. You could remove the reference operator `&` from the argument `$param1`. Or you could rollback to PHP 5.2.x if absolutely necessary.

Comment: This line had a function name Trigger_Default_Starter which I cannot find: $ins_contact->registerTrigger("STARTER", "Trigger_Default_Starter", 1, "POST", "KT_Insert1"); So... I commented out and it seems to work OK, or at least without errors. What is

Comment: "What is." <-- What do you mean by that?  Do you use an IDE for your development? If you use something like Eclipse or NetBeans you can do a global find/search..  Just hit ctrl+h (in eclipse) and search for `function Trigger_Default_Starter` and it should find it for you. If you're _not_ using an IDE then I strongly suggest that you start.  http://www.eclipse.org/projects/project.php?id=tools.pdt