# Joomla php error: Warning: Parameter 3 to plgContentPagenavigation::onContentBeforeDisplay() expected to be a reference

Tags: php, joomla2.5

I'm no php coder but I've done a little research and this looks to be an issue with different versions of php - but i could be wrong.

I'm using joomla 2.5 and get this error on checkout (using k2store):

```
Warning: Parameter 3 to plgContentPagenavigation::onContentBeforeDisplay() expected to be a reference, value given in */libraries/joomla/event/event.php on line 71

Warning: Parameter 3 to plgContentVote::onContentBeforeDisplay() expected to be a reference, value given in */libraries/joomla/event/event.php on line 71

Warning: Parameter 3 to plgContentPagenavigation::onContentBeforeDisplay() expected to be a reference, value given in */libraries/joomla/event/event.php on line 71

Warning: Parameter 3 to plgContentVote::onContentBeforeDisplay() expected to be a reference, value given in */libraries/joomla/event/event.php on line 71
```

Line 71 says:

```
return call_user_func_array(array($this, $event), $args);
```

It gives no error on my local host using php5.3.6 but on the development server I get an error with php5.3.10

[There was a similar case here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8512535/php-error-warning-parameter-1-expected-to-be-a-reference) but I did not understand the solution

Maybe this is simple for someone to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to solve by adding/remove `&` operator if given in the mentioned lines and let me know if it works or not for the time being you can turn off the error by using `error_reporting(0);` however try to debug the code first :)

Comment: Thanks very much for your help, sorry for my slow response. In the end I just disabled error reporting in the config file as you suggested since I suppose hacking the core is not really an option if I want to keep the site secure. Thanks again for your help :)